# smarter php login form validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, post

I've started learning PHP and MySQL for a while but I still consider myself a beginner!
I created a simple register form and I also wrote PHP code to validate it...
I want to know if there is a better and smarter way to accomplish my goal.
My form is based on 5 inputs: `username`, `password`, `repeat password`, `email`, `repeat email` and it sends through POST, their content and a button's value. It must check these conditions when a submit is performed:

- show error "All fields empty" if all inputs are empty
- show error "Some fields empty" if one or more inputs, but not all, are empty
- `username` length must be up to 20 chars
- `password` and `repeat password` must be equal
- passwords must be between 8 and 20 chars
- `email` and `repeat email` must be valid emails and must be equal
- show an error message of what went wrong

I wrote this function (it's inside a class) which does everything I said above but can I improve it to reduce repetitive code? Are there other PHP functions which can be used for this? And finally, how secure is my code?

Here is it!

```
public function processRegisterInfo($POSTArray = array())
{   
    if (count(array_filter($POSTArray)) > 1) // button don't have to be counted
    {
        if (count(array_filter($POSTArray)) < 6)
        {
            $this->errorMsg = "Some fields are empty";
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            $username = $POSTArray["username"];
            $password = $POSTArray["password"];
            $repPassword = $POSTArray["repPassword"];
            $email = $POSTArray["email"];
            $repEmail = $POSTArray["repEmail"];

            $isValid = TRUE;

            // Checking username length
            if (strlen($username) > 20)
            {
                $this->errorMsg .= " Username too long.";
                $isValid = FALSE;
            }

            // Checking password length and equality
            if (strcmp($password, $repPassword) == 0)
            {
                if (strlen($password) < 8)
                {
                    $this->errorMsg .= " Password must be at least 8 characters.";
                    $isValid = FALSE;
                }
                else if (strlen($password) > 20)
                {
                    $this->errorMsg .= " Password must be max 20 characters long.";
                    $isValid = FALSE;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->errorMsg .= " Passwords don't match.";
                $isValid = FALSE;
            }

            // Checking email validation and equality
            if (strcmp($email, $repEmail) == 0)
            {
                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                {
                    $this->errorMsg .= " Email provided is not valid.";
                    $isValid = FALSE;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->errorMsg .= " Emails don't match.";
                $isValid = FALSE;
            }

            if (isset($this->errorMsg) && !empty($this->errorMsg))
                $this->errorMsg = substr($this->errorMsg, 1);

            return $isValid;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->errorMsg = "All fields are empty";
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Looks good to me, it does what you want and I don't see any glaring errors.

Comment: No reason to copy the values into a new variable

Comment: I created new variables just for a better reading... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only able to use php it's as good as it's going to get i think.
These check can be performed by Jquery(javasript) to.
The pros of using jquery are, you don't have to submit it first and you can easily mark which field has a wrong value.

Comment: True but if javascript is disabled then all validation is removed. PHP validation is a must.

Comment: well, i never said ONLY to use jquery did i ? ^^